# Using z3 where constraint depends on output of function

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I want to use z3 to solve this case. The input is a 10 character string. Each character of the input is a printable character (ASCII). The input should be such that when calc2() function is called with input as a parameter, the result should be: 0x0009E38E1FB7629B.

How can I use z3py in such cases?

Usually I would just add independent equations as a constraint to z3. In this case, I am not sure how to use z3.

```
def calc2(input):
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(input)):
        r1 = (result << 0x5) & 0xffffffffffffffff
        r2 = result >> 0x1b
        r3 = (r1 ^ r2)

        result = (r3 ^ ord(input[i]))

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
        input = sys.argv[1]
        result = calc2(input)

        if result == 0x0009E38E1FB7629B:
             print "solved"
```

**Update:** I tried the following however it does not give me correct answer:

```
from z3 import *

def calc2(input):
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(input)):
        r1 = (result << 0x5) & 0xffffffffffffffff
        r2 = result >> 0x1b
        r3 = (r1 ^ r2)

        result = r3 ^ Concat(BitVec(0, 56), input[i])


    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Solver()
    X = [BitVec('x' + str(i), 8) for i in range(10)]

    s.add(calc2(X) == 0x0009E38E1FB7629B)

    if s.check() == sat:
        print(s.model())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this isn't homework, but here's one way to go about it:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# Input is 10 character long; represent with 10 8-bit symbolic variables
input = [BitVec("input%s" % i, 8) for i in range(10)]

# Make sure each character is printable ASCII, i.e., between 0x20 and 0x7E
for i in range(10):
  s.add(input[i] >= 0x20)
  s.add(input[i] <= 0x7E)

def calc2(input):

    # result is a 64-bit value
    result = BitVecVal(0, 64)

    for i in range(len(input)):
        # NB. We don't actually need to mask with 0xffffffffffffffff
        # Since we explicitly have a 64-bit value in result.
        # But it doesn't hurt to mask it, so we do it here.
        r1 = (result << 0x5) & 0xffffffffffffffff
        r2 = result >> 0x1b
        r3 = r1 ^ r2

        # We need to zero-extend to match sizes
        result = r3 ^ ZeroExt(56, input[i])

    return result


# Assert the required equality
s.add(calc2(input) == 0x0009E38E1FB7629B)

# Check and get model
print s.check()
m = s.model()

# reconstruct the string:
s = ''.join([chr (m[input[i]].as_long()) for i in range(10)])
print s
```

This prints:

```
$ python a.py
sat
L`p:LxlBVU
```

Looks like your secret string is

> "L`p:LxlBVU"

I've put in some comments in the program to help you with how things are coded in z3py, but feel free to ask for clarification. Hope this helps!

## Getting all solutions

To get other solutions, you simply loop and assert that the solution shouldn't be the previous one. You can use the following `while` loop after the assertion:

```
while s.check() == sat:
   m = s.model()
   print ''.join([chr (m[input[i]].as_long()) for i in range(10)])
   s.add(Or([input[i] != m[input[i]] for i in range(10)]))
```

When I ran it, it kept going! You might want to stop it after a while.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to z3 and I am trying to understand it. Yes, it's part of an exercise which I am working on however the methods I tried did not work. Is it possible to make z3 print all possible solutions and not just stop at one?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Would you recommend a good reference to study more about it? Most of the z3 examples given in the documentation are really basic and a lot of the techniques used in your solution are not mentioned in the documentation. It must require a lot of experience and I would like to learn more about such useful techniques. It is rare for us to apply Z3 in real world cases for simple equations like (x + y = z), (x * y = z) and so on. However, most of the information about Z3 online is for simple equations only.

Comment: http://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm is a good resource. A good collection of examples (not necessarily all in z3py) are: https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf. If you read/program in Haskell, you can also look at the examples that come with the SBV package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv

Answer (score 0):

You can encode calc2 in Z3. you'll need to unroll the loop for 1,2,3,4,..,n times (for n = max input size expected), but that's it.
(You don't actually need to unroll the loop, you can use z3py to create the constraints)

Comment: Can you provide more details with code as well? I am new to z3 and I don't know how to define constraints in this case.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to do the homework for you :)  an you show us your initial idea?

Comment: I updated the question with the code I have written. However, it does not give me correct results.